# SQL OutParameter Not Working

Tags: c#, sql, sqlparameter

```
private static SqlParameter AddNewParameterToCommand(SqlCommand command,
    string name, object value, bool isOutputParameter)
{       
    SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter();
    parm.ParameterName = name;
    parm.Value = value;
    command.Parameters.Add(parm);

    if (isOutputParameter == true)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parameter"));
    }

    return parm;
}
```

Here is what I was trying to setup but have been unable to:
If the isOutputParameter parameter is true, the new SqlParameter object is set up to accept data back from the database when the command is run.

Comment: What issue are you running into? Please give more specifics on the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [SqlParameter.Direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection.aspx) attribute.

```
if (isOutputParameter)
   {
    param.Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! What would I need to do If this SQLcommand were to have a single output paramater and I wante d to get it's value?

Answer (score 3):

```
private static SqlParameter AddNewParameterToCommand(SqlCommand command,
    string name, object value, bool isOutputParameter)
{
    SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter();
    parm.ParameterName = name;
    parm.Value = value;

    if (isOutputParameter)
    {
        parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
    }

    command.Parameters.Add(parm);

    return parm;
}
```

Ref: [SqlParameter.Direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.direction.aspx)